# How to completely remove the Start menu button from the Windows Taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-7, taskbar, start-menu, user-interface

How can one completely remove the Start menu button from the Windows 7 taskbar?

Note, that I'm *not* concerned about the Start menu still being available via `Ctrl+Esc` and other techniques.  I simply want to completely remove the Start menu button from the taskbar so other UI items can use the space.

The solution I have found so far is to use [Start Killer by TORDEX](http://www.startkiller.com/) *(note: link is HTTP, and HTTPS support for that site is not currently available)*.

That software works very well, but I'm wondering if there is a way to accomplish this without having a third-party closed-sourced app always running.

The target OS will either be Windows 7 Home Premium or Windows 7 Professional, so answers specific to either OS variant are welcome.  Ideally, answers will work on both OS variants, as I am not the one determining the target OS.